# How to change alignement in a single column of a datagridview in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I'm stuck with this issue and I can't find the answer which first seems obvious to me.

I fill my datagridview with a datatable then I want to change the alignment but only on some columns. First, I wanted to proceed like this : (dgvResultat is my datagridview)

```
        With dgvResultat
        .DataSource = dt 'Fill

        .Columns(0).HeaderText = "A"
        .Columns(0).DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter

        .Columns(1).HeaderText = "B"
        .Columns(1).DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter

        .Columns(2).HeaderText = "C"
        .Columns(2).DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter

        .Columns(3).HeaderText = "D"
        .Columns(3).DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter

        .Columns(4).HeaderText = "E"
        .Columns(5).HeaderText = "F"
        .Columns(6).HeaderText = "G"
    End With
```

I red that DefautCellStyle.Alignement was the answer to my issue in many forums, but maybe I'm using it in the wrong way...

I'm just trying to align texts which are below headers, but nothing seems to change.

Comment: Don't put answers in the question.  Accept one or post your own.

Comment: “Where” are you calling this code?

Comment: I seen that somewhere, that's why I put my answer at the end ! The thing is that I can't accept the answer when I got it from a comment... How should I do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I found a solution. This works fine for me:

```
Private Sub dgvResultat_CellFormatting(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs) Handles dgvResultat.CellFormatting
    If e.ColumnIndex >= 0 AndAlso e.ColumnIndex < 4 Then
        e.CellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't see errors... i've tryied this and it works...

You are referring that the header is not aligned??

I'm getting this...

[image]

Comment: No, headers are ok, I'm just trying to align texts which are below headers, but nothing seems to change...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
aligncenter.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
dataGridView1.Columns[0].DefaultCellStyle = aligncenter;
```

Comment: I tried, but I have the same result with this :                                                            
 Dim aligncenter As DataGridViewContentAlignment
 aligncenter = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter